# Can I use timeout's command in bash for a block of code?

Tags: bash

I would like to use `timeout` command, but It supports only to timeout a single command.

My goal is to do something like this - waiting untill a list of ports are up:

```
timeout 60 for port in $ports
do
    while ! nc -zv localhost $port; do
        sleep 1
    done
done
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo not all ports up on time
fi
```

I want the for loop to stop if 60 seconds have passed, and check if it was success or not.

I understand that I can achieve this by using something like:

```
timeout 60 bash -c "..."
```

But this will be very unreadable. I thought maybe a bash function would work as a command but it didn't work..

Any ideas?

Comment: What if, instead of writing the code in a function, writing the code in another bash script and timeout the execution of that script?

Comment: `bash` doesn't have a built-in `timeout` command; what you are running is an external program that requires an executable command as an argument, not an arbitrary fragment of shell. You need something like `timeout 60 bash -c '...'`.

Comment: I think the answer is "no, you can't".

Comment: why don't use a counter and increment it and exit from the while loop if the counter is 60 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tests, I successfully found a way to implement this using bash functions, although it looks a bit weird, it is still more readable. Here is an example:

```
function my_loop() {
    for port in $ports; do
        while ! nc -zv localhost $port; do
            sleep 1
        done
    done
}

export -f my_loop
timeout 60 bash -c "my_loop"
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
    echo not all ports up on time
fi
```